# Vue js socket.io-client on connection method not executing

Tags: vue.js, socket.io

I am creating a chat application using socket.io along with vue js. My connection code looks like this:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueSocketIO from 'vue-socket.io'
import SocketIO from "socket.io-client"

const io=SocketIO('https://example.com:8443');

Vue.use(new VueSocketIO({
    debug: true,
    connection: io
}))
```

There is no error in connection, which means the connection is done I think. And then I added on connection evening like this:

```js
io.on('connection', socket => {
  console.log("hai");
})
```

But this function is not calling when connection done. So to check I changed the port number, then the connection fails, so connection is done properly I think.

By referring to some other code, I just added like

```js
sockets: {
  connect: function() {
    console.log('socket connected')
  }
}
```

also.But didn't work.I am new to vue.How can i solve this.Thanks in advance

My console showing the follows

```
Vue-Socket.io: Received socket.io-client instance 
vue-socketio.js?5132:10 Vue-Socket.io: Vuex adapter enabled 
vue-socketio.js?5132:10 Vue-Socket.io: Vuex socket mutations disabled 
vue-socketio.js?5132:10 Vue-Socket.io: Vuex socket actions enabled 
vue-socketio.js?5132:10 Vue-Socket.io: Vue-Socket.io plugin enabled
```

Comment: Is your localhost https?

Comment: @FatimaMazhit no ,  i have hosted in my server

Comment: @FatimaMazhit i just renamed my domain to localhost thats why.But my issue is with the server